# ps - what is the difference between -o comm and -o command?

Tags: shell, centos

On CentOS 7.0.1406 I get differing output when running

```bash
ps -A -o pid,command | grep [r]esque
```

than when I run

```
ps -A -o pid,comm | grep [r]esque
```

The latter returns nothing; the former what I would expect. I was under the impression that `comm` was an alias for `command`. Could someone please explain the difference?

Comment: You might also want to look at `pgrep` for stuff like this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are not aliases, `command` outputs the *full command* and `comm` only the *command name*, so it is possible that the outputs are different. It all depends on what you want to extract the grep command.

An example:

```
$ ps -A -o pid,command | grep 9600
376 /sbin/agetty --keep-baud 115200 38400 9600 ttyS0 vt220
```

and the output for the following is empty:

```
ps -A -o pid,comm | grep 9600
```

The string `9600` is part of the complete command but the command name.

`command`, and `cmd` are aliases to `args`, with prints the command with all its arguments as string. `comm` is a different sorting code that prints only the executable name. Manpage snippet:

```
   args      COMMAND command with all its arguments as a string.

   cmd       CMD    see args. (alias args, command).

   comm      COMMAND command name (only the executable name).

   command   COMMAND see args. (alias args, cmd).
```

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, with the procps(-ng) (at least) implementation of `ps` (as is the case on CentOS):

- **`comm`** is the process name. That's retrieved from `/proc/<pid>/stat` and is limited (truncated) to 16 bytes. That's usually the basename of the first argument to the last `execve()` system call that the process (or any of its ancestors) made, unless it's a kernel thread in which case it's the kernel thread's name like `watchdog/0` or `rcu_sched` or the process has changed it with `prctl(PR_SET_NAME)`. It's the `CMD` field in the `ps` output.
- **`command`** aka `args` is the concatenation of the arguments passed to the latest `execve()` system call that the process (or any of its ancestors) made. If there was no argument (like for kernel threads), `ps` uses `[process-name]` instead (the process name as described above enclosed in square brackets). That's retrieved from `/proc/<pid>/cmdline`. That's the `CMD` field in the `ps -f` output. Note that for scripts, `execve()` is internally called again after resolution of the she-bang. Processes can also alter that value by overwriting the argv[] strings it received.

[POSIX specifies](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ps.html) `comm` (meant to be `argv[0]`) and `args` (the arg list as a string, though doesn't say how that list is to be represented (joined with spaces?)), not `command`. So the `procps` implementation is not compliant as `comm` is not the argv[0] there. Solaris, a certified implementation does have argv[0] for `comm` and has `fname` for the equivalent of procps' `comm` (as the `CMD` column in `ps` output).

Examples:

- Relation to `execve()`:

  ```
  $ ln -s /bin/sleep very-long-alias-for-sleep
  $ strace -e execve bash -c 'exec -a different-argv0 ./././very-long-alias-for-sleep 12' &
  execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "exec -a different-argv0 ./././ve"...], [/* 52 vars */]) = 0                                                  10:56
  execve("/home/stephane/././very-long-alias-for-sleep", ["different-argv0", "12"], [/* 51 vars */]) = 0
  $ ps -o comm,command
  COMMAND         COMMAND
  [...]
  very-long-alias different-argv0 12
  [...]
  ```
- `perl` overwriting both its process name and arg list:

  ```
  $ perl -e '$0 = "new name"; system("ps -p $$ -o comm,command")'
  COMMAND         COMMAND
  new name        new name
  ```
- Behaviour for scripts:

  ```
  $ cat test-script
  #! /bin/sh -e
  ps -o comm,command -p "$$"
  exit
  $ strace -e execve ./test-script arg
  execve("./test-script", ["./test-script", "arg"], [/* 52 vars */]) = 0
  COMMAND         COMMAND
  test-script     /bin/sh -e ./test-script arg
  ```

  `/bin/sh` ends up being executed with a different arg list, but the process name remains `test-script`. Here the `argv[0]` that `sh` receives is `/bin/sh`. [On some systems, it's `test-script` instead](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/#results).
- On the note about ancestors:

  ```
  $ ((((ps -o pid,comm,command;:);:);:);:)
    PID COMMAND         COMMAND
   4109 zsh             /bin/zsh
  23146 zsh             /bin/zsh
  23147 zsh             /bin/zsh
  23148 zsh             /bin/zsh
  23149 zsh             /bin/zsh
  23150 ps              ps -o pid,comm,command
  ```

  The 2314{6,7,8,9} processes never executed any command, they inherit their process name and arg list from their parent (4109) which executed /bin/zsh.

  `23150` itself initially had a process name of `zsh` like the others, but it changed to `ps` upon executing `/bin/ps`.
- use `-o 'comm'` to distinguish threads by their names:

  ```
  $ ps -T -o pid,tid,pcpu,bsdtime,comm,command -C firefox.real | sort -k3nr
    # result is sorted by third column '%CPU'
  10743 10743  4.9  14:44 firefox.real    /usr/bin/firefox.real --private-window
  10743 10775  0.3   1:01 Compositor      /usr/bin/firefox.real --private-window
  10743 10750  0.0   0:00 Gecko_IOThread  /usr/bin/firefox.real --private-window
  10743 10751  0.0   0:16 Timer           /usr/bin/firefox.real --private-window
  10743 10752  0.0   0:00 Link Monitor    /usr/bin/firefox.real --private-window
  10743 10753  0.0   0:06 Socket Thread   /usr/bin/firefox.real --private-window
  10743 10755  0.0   0:00 JS Watchdog     /usr/bin/firefox.real --private-window
  10743 10756  0.0   0:04 JS Helper       /usr/bin/firefox.real --private-window
  ...
    PID   TID %CPU   TIME COMMAND         COMMAND
  ```

Comment: What is the `-e` option used for in `#! /bin/sh -e` here ?

Comment: @QuartzCristal, that's an example of an option passed to the interpreter via the shebang. Here, `-e` is the same as `-o errexit` to enable that errexit option. Not particularly useful in that script which only has one command.

Comment: Is it that all possible `sh` programs (shells, I mean) accept the `-e` option ? If not all, then the option might not work (beside not being that useful here).

Comment: @QuartzCristal, yes `-e` is from the Bourne shell in the 70s and POSIX, so should be supported by all `sh` implementations from the last few decades. Here, the point though it to show that `-e` passed to the second execve() done upon executing the script, so what the option does is not really relevant.