# Why does shebang lead to a different process name than an explicit call?

Tags: process, proc, shebang

### Summary

Using `mirage` as an example, a python program that begins with a shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
...
```

Looking at `/proc/<pid>/comm` or using `pgrep`, it appears like ...

... the process name is "mirage" when I call it via the shebang:

```
/usr/bin/mirage &
```

... but is "python" when I call python explicitly:

```
/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/mirage &
```

- I understand that a process can change its own name, but why isn't the name the same in both cases?
- Is there a generic way to know how a process was originally launched (using only `/proc` or `grep` information)?

---

### Details - shebang

```
/home/martin> /usr/bin/mirage &
[1] 22638
```

**/proc/<pid>/comm** says it is "mirage"

```
/home/martin> cat /proc/22638/comm 
mirage
```

**pgrep** finds it as "mirage" but not as "python"

```
/home/martin> pgrep -al mirage && echo "found" || echo "not found"
22638 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/mirage
found

/home/martin> pgrep -al python && echo "found" || echo "not found"
not found
```

### Details - python

```
/home/martin> /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/mirage &
[1] 21348
```

**/proc/<pid>/comm** says it is "python"

```
/home/martin> cat /proc/21348/comm 
python
```

**pgrep** finds it as "python" but not as "mirage"

```
/home/martin> pgrep -al mirage && echo "found" || echo "not found"
not found

/home/martin> pgrep -al python && echo "found" || echo "not found"
21348 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/mirage
found
```

Comment: You can probably use `pgrep -f '^(/usr/bin/python )?/usr/bin/mirage'` to have the same result for both cases (now there must be some clever regex to allow with or without path etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that a process can change its own name, but why isn't the name the same in both cases?

Because the programs involved are *not* changing their own names.  They are given the names that the default behaviour of Linux assigns.  (Other operating systems behave differently, but this is a Linux question because it talks about `/proc/*/comm` files.)

On Linux, the program name in `comm` is taken from whatever the *program image file* name passed to `execve()` was.  Note that this *is not* either the argument vector nor the environment vector, and the statement that this name is taken from the argument vector on Linux is erroneous.

The program image file names that the shell is actually passing are `/usr/bin/python` and `/usr/bin/mirage`, so `python` and `mirage` are what `/proc/self/comm` are initialized to.  (`comm` is the basename of the program image filename, truncated/padded.)

The argument vector initializes what a process has in its `/proc/self/cmdline` and the environment vector initializes what it has in `/proc/self/environ`.  So with these and `/proc/self/comm`, and presuming that a program does not alter them when it runs, you know all three of the pieces of information that were passed to `execve()` and thus exactly "how a process was originally launched" (although, strictly speaking, this is how *the program* was launched, as *the process* was launched with `fork()`).

Here is an example of those three pieces in action, using `clearenv`, `setenv`, and `exec`  from the nosh toolset to set up a small environment and force `argv[0]` for the purposes of exposition:

```
% clearenv setenv 1THIS 'is the environment string' setenv 2COMPRISING 'all of the environment.' \
> exec -a 'This is argv[0].' /bin/sleep 100 &
[1] 15564
% for i in /proc/$\!/{comm,cmdline,environ} ; do printf "%s:" $i ; cat -v $i ; printf "\n" ; done
/proc/15564/comm:3

/proc/15564/cmdline:This is argv[0].^@100^@
/proc/15564/environ:1THIS=is the environment string^@2COMPRISING=all of the environment.^@
%
```

And indeed those are exactly what the nosh toolset's `exec` command passed to `execve()` in order to run `/bin/sleep`.  (The `3` is because `exec` uses the C library's `fexecve()` function, which internally uses program image filenames of the form `/proc/self/fd/3`.)

The program image file happening to be a script with a named interpreter and the `#!` magic number, causing substitution of that interpreter for the program image file and shifting of the argument vector, *does not change* what goes into `comm`.  It remains whatever program image filename was originally given to `execve()`.  Yes, Linux is inconsistent here, because it *does* change what goes into `cmdline` in such cases to be the effective final argument string.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/432681/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/438007/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/257568/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/392600/5132
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). "[`clearenv`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/clearenv.html)".  *Manual*.  nosh toolset.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). "[`setenv`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/setenv.html)".  *Manual*.  nosh toolset.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). "[`exec`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/exec.html)".  *Manual*.  nosh toolset.  Softwares.

Answer (score 2):

The process name is derived from `argv[0]` in the `execv()` call.

This explains the behavior that you observe.

The fact that in the shebang case the kernel rearranges how things are called does not affect the `argv` vector.